# Spring framework - How to avoid repetitive code in controller?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, controller, refactoring

Most of My controllers have repetitive codes as seen below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "process1/add.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("obj1") @Valid Object1 obj1,
        ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String tp = request.getParameter("tp");
    String co = request.getParameter("co");

    String a = request.getParameter("a");
    String successUrl = "process2/add.do?tp" + tp + "&co=" + co;
    String failureUrl = "process1/list.do?tp" + tp + "&co=" + co;

    try {
        obj1.setType(tp);
        obj1.setCode(co);
        obj1.setValue(a);
        process1Service.add(obj1, a);
        return "redirect:successUrl";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "redirect:failureUrl";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value = "process2/add.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String add(@ModelAttribute("obj2") @Valid Object2 obj2,
        ModelMap modelMap, HttpServletRequest request) {

    String tp = request.getParameter("tp");
    String co = request.getParameter("co");

    String successUrl = "process3/add.do?tp" + tp + "&co=" + co;
    String failureUrl = "process2/list.do?tp" + tp + "&co=" + co;

    try {
        obj2.setType(tp);
        obj2.setCode(co);
        process2Service.add(obj2);
        return "redirect:successUrl";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "redirect:failureUrl";
    }
}
```

I omit get-methods here, because it's easy to guess how they are.
The point is that almost my post-methods and even get-methods get url parameters named "tp" and "co".
Is there any good idea to avoid to write the repetitive codes?

Comment: Why aren't you just injecting `tp` and friends as `@RequestParam` method parameters?

Comment: Don't use parameters use an object to bind those parameters to and use the object. Spring will take care of the binding/conversion. If you name the arguments `type`, `code` and `value` you will get a fully populated model object. That is basically the wh ole point of a model object. Also your @Valid is now pretty useless as you are validating an object and modify it later on.